# Rails - Curb SSLCA error? - Curl::Err::SSLCACertificateError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, curl, ssl-certificate, curb

When I update my Rails gems I find this errors (only in production, in development environment working good):

```
Curl::Err::SSLCACertificateError
```

Seems that is an SSL Certificate Authority Error, but why only in production is not working? And what can I do to resolve the problem?

My curb gems is v.0.8.3 with rails 3.2.8
(the mayor update was the rake, that now is v.10.0.2, but I don't know if this influence the good working of the curb gem).

FYI, this is the code that raise the error:

```
    loginData = { :login => "myuser", :password => "mypass" }
    loginJson = ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(loginData)

    req = Curl::Easy.http_post("https://mysite.com", loginJson
    ) do |curl|
        curl.headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json'
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're using a self-signed SSL certificate on the server, which is fine. I do the same thing for internal services. You'll just want to make your client aware of the custom SSL certificate as well, that way it knows that it can be trusted.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
req = Curl::Easy.http_post("https://mysite.com", loginJson) do |curl|
  curl.headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json'
  curl.cacert = "/path/to/ca.crt"
  curl.cert = "/path/to/cert.pem"
end
```

Of course, you'll probably want to extract these string constants into a config file.

Comment: I haven't tested yet, but your answer is better (more secure) than mine.

Answer (score 2):

I find an alternative solution, when I request a "curl" I put this additional propriety:

```
 curl.ssl_verify_peer = false
```

I don't know if in term of security is the best solution, but for the moment it works...

Comment: Without verifying the peer, this is subject to a man-in-the-middle attack. Do not recommend.

Comment: @CodyA.Ray I know, but the server where I do the requests has a "custom" SSL Certificate (not bought from a CA). Maybe there is a more secure method to "accepts" this custom Certificate?